# Map one number range to another in bash

Tags: bash, mapping

I have a number range, for example 150 - 249, and I want to map values within this range to be in a different number range, for example 300 - 780. Is there any way I can do this in bash?

Comment: Are you trying to apply a function to them? I notice 300 is 2*150, but 780 is about 3.1 times 249, so doubling wouldn't work for you.

Comment: @numbermaniac those numbers are just examples. The actual input ranges will vary

Answer (score 0):

If the count of numbers is the same on both ranges (1:1): It is easy to create an array in bash with the target number you want:

```
$ numbers=({300..780})
```

Then, subtract 150 from the index you want:

```
$ echo "${numbers[219-150]}"
369
```

In variables:

```
sourceRangeStart=150
targetRangeStart=300
count=100

requestNumber=219

numbers=( $(seq "$targetRangeStart" $((targetRangeStart+count-1)) ) )
echo "${numbers[requestNumber-sourceRangeStart]}"
```

If the ratio is not 1:1, you need to define the function that links input to output.